# Can't access last element in Doubly Linked List when using end() in for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, linked-list, iterator

I am implementing a doubly linked List using iterators. The code works fine, except when using `iterator::end()` I am unable to access the last element in the list. For example the copy constructor cant access the last element(!!whenever I use `for(iterator it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end();++it)`). The problem looks simple but I cant get my head around it.

```
#pragma once

#include <iterator>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

template <typename T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class MyList {
private:
    class Link {
    public:
        Link(const T& d, Link *n = NULL, Link *p = NULL) :next(n), prev(p), data(d) {}
        ~Link() { }

        T data;
        Link *next;
        Link *prev;
    };
    Link *head ;
    Link *tail ;
    size_t s = 0; // ease things up

public:

    class iterator:public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, Link>
    {
    private:
        Link *itr;
    public:
        iterator() :itr(nullptr) {}
        iterator(Link* x) :itr(x) {}
       // iterator& operator=(const iterator& i2) {itr = i2.itr;}
        iterator(const iterator& i2) : itr(i2.itr) {}
        iterator& operator++() {
            itr=itr->next;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator& operator--() {
            itr = itr->prev;
            return *this;
        }


        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) {
            return itr == rhs.itr;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) {
            return itr != rhs.itr;
        }
        T& operator*() {
            return itr->data;
        }
        Link* getLink()const{
            return itr;
        }



    };

    MyList() {

        head = nullptr;
        tail= head;

        s=0;

    }

    MyList(std::initializer_list<T> l)
            :MyList(){
        for(const auto& i : l){
            push_back(i);}
    }
//copy consructor
    MyList( const MyList<T> &lst)
            :MyList(){

        for(iterator it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it){
            push_back(it.getLink()->data);
        }
    }

   MyList& operator=(std::initializer_list<T> &lst) {
        //clear any data before adding new one
        while(head){
            Link *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        s = 0;
        for(auto i: lst){
            push_back(i);
        }
    }

    MyList& operator=(MyList<T> &lst) {
        while(head){
            Link *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        s = 0;
        for(iterator it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end();++it)       {push_back(it.getLink()->data);}
    }




    ~MyList() {
        Link* temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            delete(head);
            head = temp;
        }
    }

    iterator begin() const{
        iterator i(this->head);
        return i;
    }

    iterator end() const{

        iterator return{tail};

    }

    void push_back(const T& t) {

        Link* newnode = new Link(t);
        if (empty()) {
            head = newnode;
            tail = head;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = newnode;
            newnode->prev = tail;
            tail = newnode;
        }
        s++;
    }
std::size_t size() const {
        return s;
}
bool empty() const {
        return !(this->size());
    }
};
```

This is the main.cpp I am testing my code, you can see in () when is the code working and when its failing.

```
 //test default constructor(works!!!)

        std::cout << "Testing default constructor"<< std::endl;
        MyList<int> a{};
        std::cout << "a should be empty: " << (a.empty() ? string("and it is!") : string("but it is not!")) << std::endl;

        // push_back two elements(works!!!)
        std::cout << "Testing push_back"<< std::endl;
        a.push_back(1);
        a.push_back(2);
        std::cout << "a should be 1,2, and is: " << a << std::endl;




        // test initializer list constructor(works!!!!)

        std::cout << "Testing initializer list constructor"<< std::endl;
        MyList<int> b{1, 2, 3, 4};
        std::cout << "b should be 1,2,3,4, and is: " << b << std::endl;


          //test copy constructor(doesnt work!! Misses the last element)

       std::cout << "Testing copy constructor"<< std::endl;
        MyList<int> c(b);
        std::cout << "c should be " << b << " and is: " << c << std::endl;

 MyList<int> ml{1,2,3,4,5,6};

    // (doesnt work!! misss the last element)

    for(const int& elem : ml)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ Man  of course I already tried to debug the code before posting. if you have something useful say it or don't say anything

Comment: use a sentry node! tutorial [here](http://pastebin.com/DXunz58Q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the standard convention in C++ is that `end()` points not to the last element, but to the next nonexsitent would-be element after the last.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/end/

In your implementation, `iterator end()` returns an actual last element which is obviously skipped in the `it != lst.end()` condition in the for loop:

`for(iterator it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end();++it)`

Comment: I already tried this with returning nullptr and it works for the above code, but when trying to do something like ( MyList<int> tmp{20,21,23,24}; it = ml.insert(it, ++(tmp.begin()), --(tmp.end()));) the code crashes because of --tmp.end() is null, I cant return nullptr in end

Comment: Note I *didn't* suggest to return nullptr from `end()`. It's totally wrong. You should rather return a fake/dummy element so that the iterator can be decremented. That implies you implementation is a bit flawed.